# C++ program does not allow me to give a second input

Tags: c++, for-loop, input

I have two consecutive inputs, however, my program ends before allowing me to have my second input and just runs till the end, so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
      vector<double>v1;


    for(double temp1; cin >> temp1;)
        v1.push_back(temp1);

        cout <<  "input1";

    vector<double>v2;

    for (double temp2; cin >> temp2;)
        v2.push_back(temp2);

    cout << "input2";

    return 0;
}
```

I will be given the opportunity for input in the first for loop, however, after that, it doesn't let me give a second input and just goes on to print "input2".

Comment: What is the input you're providing? How do you expect to terminate the first loop? If you enter something that can't be converted to a double or EOF you'll need to clear the error on the stream and ignore the invalid input before you can use the stream successfully again.

Comment: I would terminate the first loop with a character that isn't an int/number; what would you mean by " clear the error on the stream and ignore the invalid input before you can use the stream successfully again."?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How while(!(cin >> x)) works to re-prompt for input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173298/how-whilecin-x-works-to-re-prompt-for-input)

Comment: I kind of understand it, but there is plenty that I don't, plenty of the functions I don't actually know in general .___. , I am really new and just going through some exercises, was doing it in the same file and hence needed a new input, but now I feel like I should just start them in different files until I get a bit more advanced, to avoid such problems... >.>

Comment: The way you are doing this is valid, its just you need to manually reset `std::cin` after purposely causing it to error.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to use the fail state of `std::cin` this way. You just need to reset `std::cin` before it can be used again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
      vector<double>v1;


    for(double temp1; cin >> temp1;)
        v1.push_back(temp1);
    
    cin.clear(); //clear the error
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n'); //ignore characters until we reach \n

    cout <<  "input1";

    vector<double>v2;

    for (double temp2; cin >> temp2;)
        v2.push_back(temp2);

    cout << "input2";

    return 0;
}
```

You could also `#include <limits>` and call

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

instead, to ignore unlimited characters until `\n` is reached.